# how to retain same page using modal popup in mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I used Modal Popup in shared view,have to display that in all pages.created Partial view to show popup.It works nicely.when click submit it returns to index page(return view() and also tried with json).i need stay with modal popup once submit.Pls help me to solve

```
 $('#createPoll').click(function () {
            var url = $('#myModal2').data('url');

            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('#modalContent2').html(data);
                $('#myModal2').modal('show');
                $('form', this).submit(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: this.action,
                        type: this.method,
                        data: $(this).serialize(),
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.success) {
                                $('#modalContent2').html(data);
                                $('#myModal2').modal('show');
                            } else {
                                $('#modalContent2').html(data);
                                $('#myModal2').modal('show');
                                bindForm();
                            }
                            //        }).done(function () {
                            //            $('#myModal5').modal('hide');
                            //        });
                            //    });
                            //});
                        }

                    });
                    return false;
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: change $('#createPoll').click(function () { to $('#createPoll').click(function (e) { and at the end before }); add e.preventDefault();

Comment: Not yet working.Doesn't trigger to Action